# Individual handles for each plot in a loop

Tags: matlab, matlab-guide

I am preparing a GUI where I want to plot 2-30 different plots in a axes, and I want to add a number to each plot inside a loop iteration.

Here is my code which give me one handle (handles.handle_plotCD1), but I want handles.handle_plotCD1, handles.handle_plotCD2, handles.handle_plotCD3 etc:

```
set(handles.axes1, 'NextPlot', 'add');
for cd=1:length(plotdata)
    handles.handle_plotCD1 = plot(plotdata{cd,1}(:,1),plotdata{cd,1}(:,4),'visible','off','LineWidth',2, ...
                            'color', [0 0 0],'linestyle', '--', 'parent', handles.axes1);    
end
```

How do I do this???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it have been discussed [here](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/string-evaluation.html), dynamically named variables is not a good idea. Instead try this:

```
for cd=1:length(plotdata)
    handle_plot(cd) = ...
end
```

Obviously you can modify each `handle_plot(i)` separately.